# MySQL query grouping by ip address, user id and timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for a way to count all the records in my table between 2 dates for a certain region.

The query has to take the following requirement into account:

- Multiple rows from the same ip_from on the same day, for the same org_id can only be counted as 1.

I have a table in mysql like this:

```
+--------+----------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------+---------------------+
| org_id | org_name | user_id_from | auth_level_from |     ip_from     | region_org |      timestamp      |
+--------+----------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------+---------------------+
|      1 | test1    | NULL         | NULL            | 123.456.789.012 | Antwerpen  | 2019-03-06 00:00:00 |
|      2 | test2    | 3            | 1               | 454.454.454.454 | NULL       | 2019-03-06 00:00:00 |
|      1 | test1    | 5            | 2               | 111.111.111.111 | Antwerpen  | 2019-03-05 10:00:00 |
|      1 | test1    | 5            | 2               | 111.111.111.111 | Antwerpen  | 2019-03-05 11:00:00 |
|      1 | test1    | 5            | 2               | 111.111.111.111 | Antwerpen  | 2019-03-05 12:00:00 |
|      1 | test1    | 100          | 1               | 999.999.999.999 | Antwerpen  | 2019-03-05 12:00:00 |
+--------+----------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------+---------------------+
```

The org_id column contains the id of the organization, the org_name contains the name.

User_id_from column contains the user_id of the user who is logged in and views the profile page (an anonymous user can view this too, so it can be NULL). Auth_level_from is filled in if a user was logged in, otherwise its NULL.

ip_from contains the IP address of the user logged in via $_SERVER['remote_addr'] (I am aware that this can be altered, but it does not matter for my use case).

Region_org contains the region the organisation is in, note that an org can be in multiple regions, in this case I will insert a 2nd row exactly like the one before, but with just the region_org differently. But it can also be NULL

Finally a timestamp tracks when the event was inserted.

This is what my query looks like:

```
SELECT org_id, org_name, count(*) as total, DATE(timestamp) as date
FROM `org_profile_views_events`
WHERE region_org = 'antwerpen'
GROUP BY org_id, ip_from, DATE(timestamp)
```

But it returns the total amount for all the rows, in this example it returns

```
org_id = 1
org_name = test1
total = 4
date = 2019-03-05

org_id = 1
org_name = test1
total = 1
date = 2019-03-06

org_id = 2
org_name = test2
total = 1
date = 2019-03-06
```

While I would want it to return

```
org_id = 1
org_name = test1
total = 2
date = 2019-03-05

org_id = 1
org_name = test1
total = 1
date = 2019-03-06

org_id = 2
org_name = test2
total = 1
date = 2019-03-06
```

(since there are 3 events from the same IP on 2019-03-05 and 1 from another IP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `count(DISTINCT ip_from)`

```
SELECT org_id, org_name, count(distinct ip_from) as total, DATE(timestamp) as date
FROM `org_profile_views_events`
WHERE region_org = 'antwerpen'
GROUP BY org_id, org_name, DATE(timestamp)
```